# Change of variables for double integral

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, integration

Thank you for your time.

My basic question is whether the following change of variables allowed

$$\int_0^a \int_0^b f(a-b)g(b-c)h(c)\,dc\,db = \int_0^a \int_0^b f(c)g(b-c)h(a-b)\,dc\,db$$
I fail to find a substitutiuon that does this, but as far as I see am I having in both case a combination of positive numbers $a-b$, $b-c$ and $c$ that sums up to $a$ where all the three numbers range between $0$ and $a$.

So it was tempting for me to assume it is correct, but I fail to find a rigorous argument for this to be true.

Comment: I don't understand "I fail to find a substitution": you did wrote the substitution $(b,c)\mapsto (a-c,a-b)$, which is in fact an involution of the integration domain, as $0\le c\le b\le a$ iff  $0\le a-b\le a-c\le a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the equality is true (if e.g. $f,g,h,$ are locally integrable and $a\ge0$). Indeed, the left-hand side is $f*(g*h)$ and the right-hand side is $(f*g)*h$, where $(f*g)(x):=\int_0^x f(x-y)g(y)dy$.

You can also rewrite your equality as 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(a-b)g_1(b-c)h_1(c)\,dc\,db=((f_1*g_1)*h_1)(a) $$
$$=((f_1*g_1)*h_1))(a)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(c)g_1(b-c)h_1(a-b)\,dc\,db,$$
where $f_1(x):=f(x)$ for $x\ge0$ and $f_1(x):=0$ for $x<0$, $g_1$ and $h_1$ are defined similarly, and $(f_1*g_1)(x):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(x-y)g_1(y)dy$.